# Update or Insert code for inventory program. Had an issue with scanning the resultset

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have a problem regarding updating/ inserting data into SQL table. The code below scans for data and then decides whether to update or insert data regarding any similar data values found in the table.

However, the program didn't go through the `rs.next()` even though there is data in the table.

```
public class newInputSQL {
    Connection conx;
    public newInputSQL(String name, int quantity) {
        try {
            conx = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/InventoryBase", "Serbesius", "N01094L");
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            inputGraphin(name, quantity, conx);
        } catch (SQLException s) {
            System.err.println("SQL error: " + s.toString() + s.getSQLState() + s.getErrorCode());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            System.err.println("Class not found error: " + cnfe.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                conx.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Error while cleaning resources. Pass me a proper dustpan" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    public final void inputGraphin(String name, int quantity, Connection conn) throws SQLException {
        String inputName = null;
        Statement st = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        System.out.println("Inserting data into resultset...");
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT NAME FROM SERBESIUS.GRAPHINT WHERE NAME ='" + name + "'");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Scanning");
            inputName = rs.getString(1);
            //rs.beforeFirst();
        }
        rs.beforeFirst();
        if (inputName == null) {
            System.out.println("inserting....");
            st.execute("INSERT INTO SERBESIUS.GRAPHINT(NAME, QUANTITY) values('" + name + "', '" + quantity + "')");
        } else if (inputName.equals(name)) {
            System.out.println("Updating.....");
            st.execute("UPDATE SERBESIUS.GRAPHINT SET QUANTITY = '" + quantity + "' WHERE '" + name + "' ");
        }
        // Clean up resources.....
        rs.close();
        st.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You are doing it way more complicated than it should be.
   MySQL already has the functionality of UPSERT/MERGE.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

2. concatenated values = SQL injection.
   Use prepared statements.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

```
INSERT INTO SERBESIUS.GRAPHINT(NAME, QUANTITY) values(?,?)
on duplicate key update SET QUANTITY = quantity + ?;
```

P.s.

It is not serious to expect others to debug your code.

Comment: The URL `"jdbc:derby:` indicates Muze123 is using Derby, not MySQL

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things. The query to check if the row is already there isn't necessary - the update will do that anyway. Just run the update, check if any rows have been modified, if not do the insert.

You should also **never** concatenate values into a SQL statement. Use a `PreparedStatement` instead.

```
public final void inputGraphin(String name, int quantity, Connection conn) throws SQLException {

    PreparedStatement update = conn.createStatement("INSERT INTO SERBESIUS.GRAPHINT(NAME, QUANTITY) values (?,?)");
    PreparedStatement insert = conn.createStatement("UPDATE SERBESIUS.GRAPHINT SET QUANTITY = ? where name  = ?");

    update.setString(1, name);
    update.setInt(1, quantity);

    int rowsUpdated = update.executeUpdate();
    if (rowsUpdated <= 0) {
      insert.setInt(1, quantity);
      insret.setSting(2, name);
      insert.executeUpdate();
    }

    // !!!
    // the cleanup should be in a finally block
    update.close();
    insert.close();
}
```

---

Unrelated, but: the `Class.forName()` is no longer needed with modern JDBC drivers. The service registry introduced with Java 5 will take care of that.

But if you do think you need it, that has to be used **before** calling `DriverManager.getConnection()`.

But in your case you can simply remove the call to `Class.forName()`